# How to stop postback from running my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, postback

I have a javascript code its a small function called startLoop(), this is the function

```
function startLoop() {
            if (myInterval > 0) clearInterval(myInterval);  // stop
            myInterval = setInterval("doSomething()", iFrequency);  // run
    }
```

this function is called by Devexepress button on the client side.

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnliveTrackSubmit" runat="server" Text="Live Track" AutoPostBack="False">
<ClientSideEvents Click="startLoop()" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

this function should only execute when i click the btnliveTrackSubmit button.

but whats happening that, if i click any other serverside button that will do a post back, this function will execute.

how i can solve this?

Comment: Where do you hook it up to the server control?

Comment: Where do you attach the `startLopp` to the button

Comment: How do you start startLoop? How did you bind it to your button? Let us see the code.

Comment: Sorry, the part of the code is just disappeared by mistake, i edited it

Comment: just put a <ClientSideEvents Click="startLoop(); return false;" />

Comment: @IamStalker i did what you told me, but know i cant do any clientside things, i cant check any checkboxes, i cant click on any buttton. its like the application freezes

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved it :)

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnliveTrackSubmit" runat="server" Text="Live Track">
                                                                                                                            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { startLoop(); }" />
                                                                                                                            </dx:ASPxButton>
```